# Error Page when Site is Unreachable

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

We'll be doing a Windows update in the server and want to have a customized error page to avoid future reports of intermittent error from the users. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom error as shown by @Shirish will work.
But in case of server restart and longer system update, that page will not be displayed since the whole IIS and OS could be down. So the only way around that is having some kind of (reverse) proxy server that sits in front of your web server, which will monitor its health and then failover all requests to a different server, or just serve some error error page until web server comes back online.

For example, if you're hosting on Azure, you can have Load balancer in front of your Web App or VM. Load balancer is available if you create two services in the same Availability Set. It will monitor the health of each service in some specified interval (5 sec for example) and then route traffic accordingly. You can turn on second VM/WebApp on just when you're upgradeing first VM, to keep the cost down.

Answer (score 1):

In the web.config file place these code inside `<system.web></system.web>` and create `Error` controller and three actions `Error500` etc. and respective view pages. if `iis` returns `status 500` then the `Error500` page will be shown. You can create your own error pages.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/Error500" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/Error404" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/Error403" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: @ anand - Provide code will not work in any condition. because when server will down then your provided url will not be executed. and you will get IIS Server Error. So there is no meaning of code - <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/Error404" />

Comment: @Shirish is right, I tried this but didn't work when the whole server machine is down.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below code in `web.config`-

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
                  mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="500"
             redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

For more details of error handling check this url- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417.aspx